# i make twitter app , how i see this app ? , what is URL of my twitter app?

Tags: php, twitter

I creat new twitter app and it's show my application page .

my APP name is : testfactw

If i click to this ap i goto this page https://dev.twitter.com/apps/1495385/show

my question is what is URl of my app ?

for example https://twitter.com/XXXXXXX

actually i ahve no idea i search on google but i not found real answer.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think anyone will understand what you're asking, try to improve your question

Comment: i am asking how i am get my twitter app url .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app doesn't have a public URL. If you want a twitter page for your app you should sign up as a user and set the username to your app name. Then login to that account and create the app.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never created a Twitter app so I can't say I've got experience in doing this however, Im on the 'Create an Application' page of Twitter and it provides a 'Website' input box which says:

"**Your application's publicly accessible home page, where users can go to download, make use of, or find out more information about your application. This fully-qualified URL is used in the source attribution for tweets created by your application and will be shown in user-facing authorization screens.
(If you don't have a URL yet, just put a placeholder here but remember to change it later.)**".

This should be the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://apps.twitter.com and sign in if you haven't already. You should see a list of apps (if you have more than one)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11663822)

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin The answer is not behind the link. Going to this webpage is actually the first step of the answer (to sign in on Twitter).

Comment: True, that's what I meant @MartinZabel